# How to disable the rotation option of pie charts in iOS charts?

Tags: ios, swift3, ios-charts

If I set below property

`pieChartView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false`

then it will disable the gesture option also, but in my requirements I have to disable the rotation option.

How can I do this one?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PieChartView.rotationEnabled = false